# Delete file in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store, sqlite-net

How to delete Database file created by Sqlite-net in Windows store application. I tried this

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(databaseName);
sampleFile.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.Default);
```

but neither getting any exception nor file is getting deleted. What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try awaiting the `DeleteAsync` as well

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(databaseName);
await sampleFile.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.Default);
```